# Clamping two 2" exhaust pipes together

Tags: exhaust, muffler

I have a replacement exhaust system that I just bought. Just has a tailpipe, muffler, and a flange that connects to the header. What would be the best way to join these pipes, aside from welding it?

Each of these pipes has like a 2" OD. Can I use a tailpipe expander and just make a lapjoint and use normal exhaust clamps? Or would it be better to just use a band clamp and butt them together? Do I need to use a sealant?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to weld, you can use a joint like this:

[image]

**NOTE:** The above image is for demonstration purposes only. I couldn't readily find one which was 2" on each side.

The only difference is, the inside diameter on both ends would be 2". Your outside diameter 2" pipes would fit inside. Use two muffler clamps to attach. You'll need to match the outside diameter of the butt joint, but they would probably be 2 1/8" clamps.